# How to do Grafana Loki HTTP API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, grafana-loki

I need to do this kind of [Grafana Loki HTTP API](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#query-loki-over-a-range-of-time) in javascript.

Something like this:

```bash
$ curl -G -s "http://whatever:3100/loki/api/v1/query_range" --data-urlencode 'query={job="bobjob", branch=~"master"} |= ` ` '
```

How do I do that in javascript?

- With `fetch()` I run into the problem that you can't do "GET" and also have a body for the `query` section.
- With `XMLHttpRequest()` I run into CORS issues.

Comment: Could you do a POST method and provide the query as a URL-encoded string in the request body?  (...using Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wyck was right about the POST thing. That's the short answer.

But to give the long answer for any future person reading this who needs it spelled out a bit more:

```js
fetch("http://whatever:3100/loki/api/v1/query_range", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: 'query={job="bobjob", branch=~"master"} |= ` ` '
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

When VIA is connected, it works. When it's not, the CORS issue reemerges.